# Can't use data for fontawesome icons in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, font-awesome

Here I am trying to get individual icons for subclasses here

```
             <v-col v-for="sub in subclasses" :key="sub.sub">
              <div class="d-flex justify-center">
                <v-btn
                  @click="goTo(sub.title)"
                  class="mb-2"
                  color="rgb(54, 61, 68)"
                >
                  <font-awesome-icon
                    class="fa-2x"
                    :icon="['fa', sub.icon]"
                  />
                </v-btn>
              </div>
              <p class="text-center">{{ sub.title }}</p>
            </v-col>
```

And my data looks like this:

```
subclasses: [
    {
      title: "Ancestral Guardian",
      value: 1,
      icon: "paw",
    },
    {
      title: "Battlerager",
      value: 2,
      icon: "user-secret",
    },
    
  ],
```

This causes this error:
Could not find one or more icon(s) {prefix: 'fas', iconName: 'paw'}iconName: "paw"prefix: "fas"[[Prototype]]: Object {}